# Hibernate Query (or criteria): using Count in Where Clause

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have 1 class following:

```
public Class Customer{
  @id
  int id;
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "ParentID")
  Customer parentId
}
```

How can I select all Customer which have total **Children** less more than 2?

Comment: where is @OneToMany relationship

Comment: and List of children ids

Comment: How can I do it with query. I dont want to use many transaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by the parent entity filtering according the amount of associated customers

```
SELECT p 
FROM Customer c JOIN c.parentId p 
GROUP BY p 
HAVING COUNT(c) > 2
```

Please check if having condition is what you want.

This query should be supported if the Hibernate version fully implements the JPA Specification (in JPA 2.1 specs see section 4.7).

I am not sure if Hibernate allows to do that. If you suffer any trouble, consider what says in [HH - The group by clause](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-grouping) and be aware about non-aggregated properties.

Answer (score 0):

Use following type of query. This is only for reference. Make changes in code according to your requirement.

```
select Customer.customerId , count(Customer.children)
from Customer
group by Customer.customerId
having count(Customer.children)  > 2
```

I am assuming you'll add childrens using @OneToMany relationship.